# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I was building a django project in that I need to create an edit option for a particular model named SchoolDetail. But while fetching the data from this table using id, its showing the above error

**views.py**

```
def SchoolPage(request):
school_details = SchoolDetail.objects.all()
school_details_pk = school_details.id



context = {'school_details': school_details, 'school_details_pk':school_details_pk}
return render(request, 'busschool.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class SchoolDetail(models.Model):
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank= True, null=True)
school_place = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank= True, null=True)
school_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank= True, null=True)
school_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank= True, null=True)
school_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank= True, null=True)
is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.school_name
```

**template**

```
enter code here
<tbody>
                    {% for i in school_details %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.school_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_place}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_email}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_address}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.is_verified}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'schooledit' school_details_pk %}">click</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
<tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers
I find a solution

```
<tbody>
                    {% for i in school_details %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.school_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_place}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_email}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_address}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.school_phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.is_verified}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'schooledit' i.id %}">click</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to this row: **school_details_pk = school_details.id.**
You can refer to the example for the first id:

```
school_details[0].id
```

Also iterate over all id in a loop:

```
for i in school_details:
    print(i.id)
```

Comment: I need all the data from the table, not a specific one. So I think the first method can't work. For the second one how we can call each id into the template

Comment: I wanted to answer, but I see you did it yourself.